# Sort by key values in Swift CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, core-data

How can I sort CoreData query by field values?

For example:
I have rows with field "type". I want to get results sorting firstly by `type = "car"`, then by `type = "bike"`, then by `type = "truck"`.
Something like:

```
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "type=car,type=bike,type=truck", ascending: true)]
```

Is it possible in Swift's CoreData? Thanks

*P.S. Swift version >= 3*

Answer (score 0):

I think the NSSortDescriptor is intended for a single key at a time, but I reckon you'd be able to do something similar via a loop.

```
keys = ["car", "bike", "truck"]
var descriptors = []

for key in keys {
    let descriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: key, ascending: true)
    descriptors.append(descriptor)
}

request.sortDescriptors = descriptors
```

Comment: This wouldn't work because you are sorting on the value of a field/attribute of the core data model.

i.e. The field will be "Type", so you can't sort it by "car" you can only sort by "type"

But you are correct in that you can only have one key in a sort descriptor at a time

Answer (score 0):

You are only able to sort by one key at a time with NSSortDescriptor. So you would need to use an array of NSSortDiscriptor's to achieve the idea of what you want to do.

But it doesn't seem like you are understanding the fundamentals of sorting by a field on a core data model.

You can only sort by the key `type`. Not by *"car"*, *"bike"*, *"truck"*.

So you could do an alphabetical sort on `type` or you can make a custom sort descriptor where you determine the precedence of each key value which would then sort the key any way you like

```
NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "type", ascending: true) { (lhs, rhs) -> ComparisonResult in
    /* calculation for your custom sort order */
}
```

Comment: I understand the fundamentals of the Core Data. The question is about possibilities of a class and about the syntax. It's possible to do what I'm asking about in SQL queries.